# PHP datetimestamp formatting

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, formatting

I currently have a datetimestamp in the following format when posted from a form: `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` however I am trying to convert it to the appropriate format before MySQL insertion which is in the following format: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. The `ss` seconds will always be `0`.

Is it correct to use `strtotime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes so you should use the following:

```
$form_date = $_POST['form_date'];
$date_insert = date('Y-m-d H:mm:0', strtotime($form_date));
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately it keeps displaying 1970

Comment: could you echo what gets posted from the form?  i ran this exact command and it seems to spit out the answer.

Comment: It echoes the following: `1970-01-01 00:0101:0`

Comment: could you show me the format of what is getting posted from the form.  are you using the jquery datepicker plugin, because you can specify the format that gets passed in to your post; this might be the issue.

Comment: Of course, so when the value from the datetime form field is posted it is the following: `echo $date_time;` which echoes 25/02/2011 23:45.

Comment: try this then `$form_date = substr($_POST['form_date'],2);` looks like you have 2 added characters in the front.

Comment: Unfortunately it still displays the same values: `$date_time = substr($_POST['date_time'],2);
$date_insert = date('Y-m-d H:mm:0', strtotime($date_time));
echo $date_insert;` which echoes `1970-01-01 00:0101:0`

Comment: wait did those characters disappear, before when i wrote my last comment there were added // before the 25.  actually i just noticed too, the month and day aren't in the proper place you need to swap those values, then it should work.  if you're using a jquery datepicker plugin you can change that format in the settings.

Comment: I shall take a look at the settings for date picker, hopefully it should work. Thanks for all your help @Robert Van Sant.

Comment: actually i have another fix do this `$form_date = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['form_date']);` and this should do it, otherwise move forward with the datepicker settings - best wishes and do update me :)

Comment: It worked! I guess the slashes and dashes were causing issues then. Also I edited a small part of the formatting to `date('Y-m-d H:i:00', strtotime($form_date));` so now it outputs `2011-02-25 23:45:00` Thanks @Robert for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safer to use strptime, because of month-day-year / day-month-year inconsistence.

```
print_r(strptime($date_in_mdy_format, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use strtotime, and that would be

```
$mysqldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($mydate));
```

Then you put the `$mysqldate` in the SQL query.

Also see [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) .